# how does StartActivityIfNeeded() work with REORDER_TO_FRONT?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, start-activity

I am in an **Activity A** and make a call to another **Activity B** using the 
`startActivityIfNeeded()` method with the `REORDER_TO_FRONT` flag because the **Activity B** is inside the activities stack but I don't know what life cycle method this `startActivityIfNeeded()` method makes the call.

```
Intent mIntent = HomeActivity.callingIntent(CartActivity.this, bundle, false, true);
                    mIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                    startActivityIfNeeded(mIntent, 0,
                            ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(CartActivity.this, llTransitionBar, "navigationBarTransition").
                                    toBundle());
```

Question: What method of the life cycle of an `Activity` does the `StartActivityIfNeeded()` call with the `REORDER_TO_FRONT` in case the Activity I want to call if it is within the **Activity Stack** ?, 'cause I want to implement input transitions in the new `Activity`

Comment: Please use english as language for the question.

Comment: @maycol99 Please, translate the question or use localized version of SO (https://es.stackoverflow.com for spanish). In that case more people will be in position to help you.

Comment: ok i already edited my question

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if `ActivityA` is launching `ActivityB`, then you don't **ever** need to use `startActivityIfNeeded()`, because this call would **never** return `false`, it would **always** actually launch an instance of `ActivityB` and return `true`. Instead you should just use `startActivityForResult()`.

If you use `startActivityForResult()` with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` and there is already an instance of `ActivityB` in the stack, you should see the following lifecycle calls:

- `ActivityA.onPause()`
- `ActivityB.onNewIntent()`
- `ActivityB.onResume()`